# ngModel value is not updating in directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a directive for color picker and value of ngModel value is not being updated. Any idea whats going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
            .directive('colpkr', [function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    theme : "@theme",
                    ngModel : "="
                },
                link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                    theme = scope.theme || "light";

                    $(iElement).colpick({
                        layout:'hex',
                        submit:0,
                        colorScheme:theme,
                        onChange:function(hsb, hex, rgb, iElement, bySetColor) {
                            if(!bySetColor) scope.ngModel = '#' + hex;
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
```

Comment: I think you might want to require ngModel rather than make it part of the directives scope. That way you're getting a reference to the model controller and not just a value in a child scope.

Comment: Can you create a plunker with a small working sample of your code. I'd like to try and see if I can get it working with `require` rather than `scope`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to trigger a `digest loop`, which Angular uses to update the DOM, manually in your directive. `scope.$apply()` is an option, but you may encounter `Error: $digest already in progress`.

So you'd better use `evalAsync` or `applyAsync` to trigger a safe digest cycle,like

```
scope.$evalAsync(function () {
  scope.ngModel = '#' + hex;
});
```

Or you can merge these two options, do like some Angular built-in [directives](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/e057a9aa398ead209bd6bbf76e22d2d5562904fb/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js)

```
if ($rootScope.$$phase) {
  scope.$evalAsync(callback);
} else {
  scope.$apply(callback);
}
```

Comment: let me try this one too!

Comment: @Shreejibawa please note that `evalAsync` is available only after Angular 1.1 and `applyAsync` for Angular 1.3.8 +

Answer (score 2):

You might want to refresh scope.

Use

```
onChange:function(hsb, hex, rgb, iElement, bySetColor) {
    if(!bySetColor) scope.ngModel = '#' + hex;
    scope.$apply();
}
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks! how could I've missed this?

Answer (score 0):

Inject `$parse` service in your `directive`.  Then you can `$parse(attrs.ngModel)` to which you can `assign` the `new value`.

```
// inject $parse service in your directive
// Your link function
function link(scope, el, attrs) {
    el.on('change', function() {
        scope.$evalAsync(function() {
            var
                // parse the ngModel
                ngModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel),
                // get the new value
                newValue = el.val();
            // 
            ngModel.assign(scope, newValue);
        })
    })
}
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Worked like a charm**

```
  scope.$evalAsync(function() {

       var ngModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel),

       newValue = 'Its working';

       ngModel.assign(scope, newValue);
  });
```